# Ledger Blue and Ledger Live

Tags: ledger, ledger-blue

I bought XLM and wanted to store it on my Ledger Blue. I read another post that this supposed to be possible and yet is seems impossible. Is Ledger Blue actively supported? Ledger Live is now available, will wallet become available on Ledger Live?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Ledger Blue is supported. You need to install the Stellar app from the Ledger Manager. Ledger Live itself does not support Stellar at this time, but you can use the Ledger with several online wallets and DEX applications such as the [Stellar account viewer](https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/#!/), [Stellarterm](https://stellarterm.com/), [Stellarport](https://portal.stellarport.io/home), and [Stellar Laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/) among other tools.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a Ledger Nano in the past and it worked great. I had to do two things first though (ymmv):

1. Update to the Ledgers firmware to the latest version.
2. Install the Stellar 'app' onto the Ledger using the desktop client.

Once you've completed those steps, you can sign transactions, etc., using the [laboratory](https://www.stellar.org/laboratory/) and the [account viewer](https://www.stellar.org/account-viewer/#!/).

[Stellar Term](https://stellarterm.com/#account) also accepts Ledger Wallets.